# how to get values in ajax without data

Tags: json, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 
    url: 
    data: 
    contentType: 
    dataType: 
    success: function() {
}
})
```

Above code is the ajax syntax  .My question is how to get values in ajax without data attriute?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `type: "GET"` and remove `data`

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'test.php',
 type: 'GET' //default 
 success: function(data){
   //do something with data
   console.log(data);
 }
 error: function(errHere){
  console.log(errHere.responseText);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The data attribute is optional. You can just remove it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 
    url: 
    contentType: 
    dataType: 
    success: function() {
    }
});
```

You can read more about the syntax [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The statement needs a value and a comma after "type:", "url:" etc. Besides that: why don't you simply skip the "data:"-line when you don't need it? It is used to send a parameter to your server-side something, in most cases it is used as a parameter for a database query or similar. You do not need to send it.